# Declaring variable as interface and accessing properties of specific implementation

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, netty

In an application I am developing, I am decoding TCP-messages. These messages all have the same header, but the actual message content can have different fields and a different total length. So I thought of the following implementation, which I'm assuming is not correct.

I have defined an interface for the messages containing only the header:

```
internal interface IMesTelegram
{
    public MesTelegramHeader Header { get; set; }
}

internal class MesTelegramHeader
{

    public ushort Id { get; set; }
    public ushort SenderId { get; set; }
    public ushort ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public byte MessageType { get; set; }

    public ushort DataLength { get; set; } 

}
```

I have then implemented a Telegram-class which implements the header:

```
internal class MesTelegram : IMesTelegram
{
    public MesTelegramHeader Header { get; set; }

}
```

And then I have specific telegram-classes, which are based on the MesTelegram-class:

```
internal class MesAckTelegram : MesTelegram
{
    public byte AckReject { get;set; }
    public ushort MessageId { get; set; }
    public ushort ResponseId { get; set; }

    public uint ResponseTimeOut { get; set; }

}

internal class MesVersionInfoTelegram : MesTelegram
{
    public ushort InterfaceVersionMajor { get; set; }

    public ushort InterfaceVersionMinor { get; set; }
    public ushort StringLength { get; set; }

    public string SoftwareVersion { get; set; }


}
```

Here's where the telegrams get decoded. I thought it was okay to declare an IMesTelegram variable and then assign the specific implementation to it, but that is not working.

```
protected override void Decode(IChannelHandlerContext context, IByteBuffer input, List<object> output)
{
    MesTelegramHeader header = new();

    header.Id = input.ReadUnsignedShortLE();
    header.SenderId = input.ReadUnsignedShortLE();
    header.ReceiverId = input.ReadUnsignedShortLE();
    header.MessageType = input.ReadByte();
    header.DataLength = input.ReadUnsignedShortLE();

    IMesTelegram mesTelegram = null;

    switch (header.Id)
    {
        case 123:
            mesTelegram = new MesVersionInfoTelegram();
            // i thought i could access the properties here, but i can't
            break;
        case 456:
            mesTelegram = new MesAckTelegram();
            // i thought i could access the properties here, but i can't
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    mesTelegram.Header = header;

}
```

I don't think I've chosen the right approach here, and I am not sure what the best way to continue would be. I thought by using an interface I could keep the code short. The next step would be to convert the telegram into a message for a different system, depending on the original telegram type. I thought I could pass an IMesTelegram to that method, check the header.Id and continue based on that. I'm grateful for any help or pointers.

Comment: Is this for an actual production scenario or for educational purposes. If the former: why not choose from one of the vastly available serialization formats like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data-serialization_formats ?

Comment: since `mesTelegram` is of the type `IMesTelegram` it cannot know the propertys neither the baseclass nor the interface have acces to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `mesTelegram` is of the interface-type that has no notion of the specifics. So just create a variable of the specific type and assign that to your `mesTelegram`-variable:

```
protected override void Decode(IChannelHandlerContext context, IByteBuffer input, List<object> output)
{
    MesTelegramHeader header = new();

    header.Id = input.ReadUnsignedShortLE();
    header.SenderId = input.ReadUnsignedShortLE();
    header.ReceiverId = input.ReadUnsignedShortLE();
    header.MessageType = input.ReadByte();
    header.DataLength = input.ReadUnsignedShortLE();

    IMesTelegram mesTelegram = null;
    switch (header.Id)
    {
        case 123:
            var m1 = new MesVersionInfoTelegram();
            // ... set the specific props here
            mesTelegram = m1;
            break;
        case 456:
            var m2 = new MesAckTelegram();
            mesTelegram = m2;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if(mesTelegram != null)
        mesTelegram.Header = header;

}
```

Comment: I think you cannot declare two `var m` in a switch this might not compile.
And you wont have access to the specific props after. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Seems like I missed something obvious! Introducing a new variable did the trick, but it can't be the same variable name, because then I'm getting a compiler error: A local variable or function named 'm' is already defined in this scope. Using different variables for each case did the trick, so i.e. `var infoTelegram = new MesVersionInfoTelegram();
mesTelegram = infoTelegram;`

Comment: I'd use `IMesTelegram mesTelegram = header.Id switch { 123 => new MesVersionInfoTelegram { /* Set Props*/ }, 456 => new MesAckTelegram { /* Set Props */ } , _ => null};` to circumvent these problems.

Comment: ^^ P.S. I'd actually throw an exception on unknown Type ID.

Comment: @Fildor I agree, however I just used OPs original code which doesn't throw in that case (to wait for an NRE to happen).

Comment: I totally get that. Just wanted to hint OP to that option.